# Can the write spell copy maps or pictures?

Tags: spells, adnd-1e

Can *write* be used to copy maps or pictures of a non-magical nature?

Answer (score 6):

## No.

Unless the DM has ruled otherwise, the spell *write* only copies spells.

> **Write** (Evocation)
>   Level: 1
>   Components: V, S, M
>   Range: 0
>   Casting Time: 1 round
>   Duration: 1 hour/level
>   Saving Throw: Special
>   Area of Effect: One magical spell inscription
>
> Explanation/Description: **By means of this spell a magic-user might be able to inscribe a spell to make a magical scroll he or she cannot understand at the time** (due to level or lack of sufficient intelligence) **into the tome or other compilation he or she employs to maintain a library of spells.** The magic-user must make a saving throw versus magic to attempt the writing of any spell, +2 if it is only up to 1 level greater than he or she currently uses, 0 at 2 levels higher, and -1 per level from 3 levels higher onwards. If this throw fails, the magic user is subject to 1d4 of damage for every level of the spell he or she was attempting to transcribe into his or her magic book, and furthermore be knocked unconscious for a like number of turns. This damage, if not fatal, can only be healed at the rate of 1-4 points per day, as it is damage to psyche and body. Furthermore, a spell will take 1 hour per level to transcribe in this fashion, and during this period, the magic-user is in a trance state and can always be surprised by any foe. In addition to the writing surface upon which the spell is to be transcribed, the spell caster needs a fine ink composed of rare substances (minimum cost 200 g.p. per bottle, if available at all without manufacture by the magic user).

Emphasis mine. That's all the spell does. A "magical spell inscription" *containing* as part of its inscription a map or illustration *may* copy the map or illustration into the magic-user's tome as part of using the spell *write*, but that, too, would be the DM's call.

Comment: "would be the DM's call" - and so a House Rule is made. Sounds like a good one.